# JGitflow triggers concourse job infinitely

Tags: jgit, concourse, jgitflow-maven-plugin, concourse-git-resource, concourse-pipeline

I'm using JGitFlow with Concourse.

I have two branches - master and develop. My job is triggered when there is a change to develop.

When the job is run, it executes `mvn -X --batch-mode jgitflow:release-start jgitflow:release-finish`

The issue is that when jgitflow runs, its bumps version numbers, updates the snapshot, tags and merges with master. Finally, it pushes the changes back to develop and master.

Since jgitflow made changes to develop (updated snapshot version), it causes Concourse job to be triggered again.

Is there a way of avoiding this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the commit message? If you can, adding `[ci skip]` to the commit message will cause the `git` resource to ignore that commit (it will pull down the version if it's triggered another way, though. It just skips it for checking purposes)